# OpenGL Docker example requires --net=host, is there an alternative?

Tags: docker, x11, nvidia-jetson

This is a question about Docker networking and running an OpenGL GUI application within a docker container.

[This example](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/opengl-apps-cant-run-in-docker-conttainer-on-jetson-nano/118336/3) shows that to get this particular OpenGL example to run in a Docker container that the `--net=host` option must be provided.  Certainly, the example doesn't work correctly without that option.

My question is, if I don't want to specify `--net=host` because I want it to be part of a different network, then is there a way to specify some other options when creating the container that will cherry-pick the exact network changes or port mappings required to get it to run?

I don't fully understand *why* it needs the `--net=host` option.  (I think it has something to do with the X11 server??)  Previously (before my container was using OpenGL) there was a `mynetwork` network that my container was using to speak to other docker containers on the system.  And so it was being launched with `--net=mynetwork`.  But now, specifying `--net=host` instead, gets the new OpenGL features working, but breaks the features that required communication with the other docker containers on the `mynetwork` network.

I seek to better understand why OpenGL requires `--net=host` and if there's something else I can do besides `--net=host` to correctly enable whatever the container actually needs with respect to host networking so that I can both 1) communicate with my other containers on the `mynetwork` network, and 2) use the OpenGL features.

Maybe there's a way involving setting `DISPLAY` and/or `XAUTHORITY` to some values that will let the container connect to the host correctly?  Possibly there's an additional step involved on the host to permit this (beyond just `xhost +`)?

For completeness, here is the aforementioned example (intended to be run on an NVIDIA Jetson Nano).  Seeking an alternative to `--net=host` is the relevant part of my question.

```sh
$ xhost +
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --net=host --runtime nvidia -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.3.1
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make g++
$ /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/cuda-install-samples-10.0.sh /tmp
$ cd /tmp/NVIDIA_CUDA-10.0_Samples/2_Graphics/simpleGL
$ make
$ ./simpleGL
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but I think it has something to do with IndirectGLX. I don't really understand why the nvidia examples have you mount in the `/tmp/.X11-unix/` either when it's not even needed if you use `--net host`. Anyways I tried for a while to see if I could get IndirectGLX to make it work but I didn't have any luck.